# How to interpret cassandra consistency from tracing a query

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

Could you advice even though my query do not have option 
IF EXISTS and IF NOT EXISTS.
still in query tracing result shows both consistency_level "QUORUM" which is what we wanted

but it also shows 'serial_consistency_level': 'SERIAL', what is this behavior

```
 session_id                           | client      | command | coordinator | duration | parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | request                     | started_at
--------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------
 278a2000-3dfb-11e9-b459-9775e6c46fc6 | 10.244.*.* |   QUERY |  10.244.*.* |     3338 | 
`

`{'bound_var_0_stream_id': '''3c17230d-ea24-4ff7-9599-352fef883b31''', 
 'bound_var_1_property_name': '''Location:rxRSSI''', 
 'bound_var_2_shard_date': '2019-03-03T00:00:00.000Z', 
 'bound_var_3_time': '2019-03-03T21:27:30.749Z', 
 'bound_var_4_source_id': '''fe30653c-467f-401a-9646-67b10378e1c9''', 
 'bound_var_5_time_lag': '1328', 
 'bound_var_6_property_class': '''java.lang.Integer''', 
 'bound_var_7_property_type': '''ByteType''', 
 'bound_var_8_property_value': '''-44''', 
 'consistency_level': 'LOCAL_QUORUM', 
 'page_size': '5000', 
 'query': 'INSERT INTO "cloudleaf"."stream_48" ("stream_id", "property_name", "shard_date", "time", "source_id", "time_lag", "property_class", "property_type", "property_value") 
 VALUES (:"stream_id", :"property_name", :"shard_date", :"time", :"source_id", :"time_lag", :"property_class", :"property_type", :"property_value") 
 USING TTL 432000', 
 'serial_consistency_level': 'SERIAL'}
```

Answer (score 2):

`IF EXISTS` and `IF NOT EXISTS` trigger a lightweight transaction, which can have one of the two consistency levels `SERIAL` or `LOCAL_SERIAL`. Those are defined as follows:

`SERIAL`:
Achieves linearizable consistency for lightweight transactions by preventing unconditional updates. This consistency level is only for use with lightweight transaction. Equivalent to QUORUM.

`LOCAL_SERIAL`:
Same as SERIAL but confined to the datacenter. A conditional write must be written to the commit log and memtable on a quorum of replica nodes in the same datacenter.  Same as SERIAL but used to maintain consistency locally (within the single datacenter). Equivalent to LOCAL_QUORUM.

see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigSerialConsistency.html